# response.flushBuffer() giving me an error while opening excel file programmatically at client side

Tags: java, jquery, excel, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I have to export data from my jqdrid to excel file. I am able to prepare the data in string format in my javaascript code like below

```
"1\tRamu Kaka\tShanta Ben\tN Modi\tSome clerk\tCustomer\tECP\tFunding\t80.00\tTBill\tMinus\t1,111\t\t\t01-01-1900\t01-01-1900\t\t\tSubmitted\t01-01-1900\tYes\t\t;2\tRamu Kaka\tShanta Ben\tN Modi\tSome clerk\tCustomer\tECP\tFunding\t80.00\tTBill\tMinus\t1,111\t\t\t01-01-1900\t01-01-1900\t\t\tSubmitted\t01-01-1900\tYes\t\t;....."
```

and able to get the same in my MVC controller like below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/exportToXLS", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView exportToXL(@RequestParam("data") String data,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Model model) throws Exception {

    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", Integer.toString(data.length()));
    String dateString = dtFormat.format(new Date());
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;    filename=\"FileName-" +dateString+ ".xls\";");
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

    Workbook workbook =  myExcelUtility.exportTasks(Arrays.asList(data.split(";")));
    workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());     

    response.flushBuffer();//<--- here

    return null;
}
```

In my **myExcelUtility.exportTasks(Arrays.asList(data.split(";")));** method I am preparing Workbook by populating all the cellItem, Style, values etc.

Upto here things are fine.

But the time I do response.flushBuffer();, My application's page get navigated to some URL and says

**"Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"**

There url URL where it goes is

http://:5080/myApp/exportToXLS?data=1\tRamu Kaka\tShanta Ben\tN Modi\tSome clerk\tCustomer\tECP\tFunding\t80.00\tTBill\tMinus\t1,111\t\t\t01-01-1900\t01-01-1900\t\t\tSubmitted\t01-01-1900\tYes\t\t;2\tRamu Kaka\tShanta Ben\tN Modi\tSome clerk\tCustomer\tECP\tFunding\t80.00\tTBill\tMinus\t1,111\t\t\t01-01-1900\t01-01-1900\t\t\tSubmitted\t01-01-1900\tYes\t\t;.....

There is no error logs in my server console.

There can not be anything wrong in creating Workbook becase I also tried with

```
Workbook workbook =  new HSSFWorkbook();
workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());     
response.flushBuffer();
```

But this is also of no use.

Could you please help me to find out what and where I am making any mistake.

Comment: I recommend using firefox for debugging or switching the "friendly html error messages" off under advanced options. There is quite likely a stacktrace or another error showing that internet explorer is hiding from you.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294807

Comment: Let me try that Joe. Thanks

Comment: Its working in FF and Chrome :)

Comment: well that's good news at least :) it is always and without fail IE (when it's not safari) that is giving problems. Personally I recommend always having FF ready for testing, and only checking IE when you have to. In this case, Perhaps IE is trying to actually open the excel file rather than let you saveAs? It sounds like this issue is more to do with IE than with java, though something you're writing to the output stream is causing this. perhaps a missing header / content type / something?

Comment: Switched the comments to an answer, as who knows it might be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your content disposition contains a semicolon (;) at the end
based on [this link](http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html) I think you should change:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;    filename=\"FileName-" +dateString+ ".xls\";");
```

it should be

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"FileName-" +dateString+ ".xls\"");
```

Also depending on how old the instance of IE is, you may need to change the content-type

> Ancient browsers also required the following (not needed nowadays, but
>   for a fool proof solution might be worth doing):
>
> ```
> Content-Type header should be before Content-Disposition.
> Content-Type header should refer to an unknown MIME type (at least until the older browsers go away).
> ```

This might not be needed anymore but it can be worth trying out. If the header is a known mime-type it might cause the browser to try to execute it.

Comment: Yes, you are correct in setting "Content-Disposition". Thre should not be any "?". But the order of setting Content-Type and Content-Disposition does not make any difference. There is some issue with my data that I am creating in my javascript that is also only the last row. Still struggling to find out, What. Upto nine rows I am able to export data in excel and open it as well. Thanks for your continous comments and help.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I can see is that you're sending the wrong Content-Length.
What you're doing is sending the character length of the "data" parameter, which is definitely not the length of the excel file binary size, which is what the Content-Length should actually be. Make sure you calculate it and send that instead.

The return type of the exportToXL method should be void, because you're not going to be using a spring view/model. You're writing the binary output yourself.

Comment: Actually, while searching the solutions I added this line. Earlier I was not even setting this attribute. But let me try to get the binary length and set it. Thanks for the suggesstion.

Comment: No, Tried with response.setHeader("Content-Length", Integer.toString(data.getBytes().length*8)); but did not work.

Comment: @Jaikrat The point was that you are writing "workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());" to the response outstream. but you are telling response it's content length = data.size().   these are 2 different amounts. I hope this is the point the OP was making

Comment: Don't return the size of the "data" parameter. That's just the input string. You're sending an excel file, which has a different binary size than the raw string. If that is too hard, it shouldn't be a problem to omit the Content-Length header altogether. Try it without it. Also, make the return type of the exportToXL method to be void, since you're not going to be using a model/view.

Comment: I had tried without setting "Content-Length" earlier as well and as per your suggesstion tried again. But did not work.

Comment: Did you try doing `public void exportToXL` instead of `public ModelAndView exportToXL` ?

Comment: Yes John. Tried with both.

Comment: Try also removing the cache-control, pragma and expires headers and see how that goes. By the way, have you tried any other browsers?